# How do I play COD 4 with my friend at a different house?

Tags: call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I have been playing *Call of Duty 4 - Modern Warfare* for a couple of days with my friends on the same network now, and was wondering if there is any way to play it with my friends sitting back at our houses, playing on different networks together.

My PC is Windows 8 and my friend's is Windows 10.

Comment: Depends,if you both bought it from the steam then steam does it for you. If you bought it from the windows store and he bought it from steam then sadly it won't work

Comment: Did you get it on Steam?

Answer (score 2):

You can join online servers in "Join Game" and "Internet" section, and also you can use online parties like Garena or Gameranger. you can also host your own server so you can play 1v1 on free.war24.net/create/cod4.
you can also create a server on a web host if you host one.